# How can I have merge conflicts between 2 branches with common ancestor?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

We have recently encountered a really odd issue using git while trying to merge two branches. The situation boils down to the following:

1. branch `A` is some long-lived branch we want to merge back to main trunk `B` which has some other commits
2. We want to merge `B` in `A` and then `A` back into `B`
3. When doing `git checkout A; git merge B` we encounter merge conflicts which are unrelated to the changes introduced by `A`: Those are located into a bunch of files that are supposedly untouched by `A` but changed in `B`
4. Using `git annotate` and `git log` to trace the ancestry of one of the  conflicting file we effectively notice that the conflicting locations have a common commit ancestry `1234`: One line is annotated with `1234` in `A` and `5678`  in `B` but `git annotate file1 5678^` shows `1234` for the conflicting line.

I do not understand how this is possible and could not find any clue on a similar issue anywhere.

Comment: `git blame` aka `git annotate` has to linearize the un-linear-izable, while `git merge` (and `git merge-base --all`) looks at the actual graph, so it may be interesting to see what `git merge-base --all A B` produces as its commit hash ID or IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) ! Nothing surprising in the resulting commit I should say, nor in its history.

Comment: OK - well, I'd need to see more to have some idea why you are getting the merge conflict you are getting. But you can do `git diff --find-renames <base> A` and `git diff --find-renames <base> B` to see *what* Git sees, when it declares this conflict. *Why* (in terms of commits) is trickier.

Comment: Yes, I know it's hard without a lot of details. And I cannot provide those for a closed-source piece of software of course. Thanks for your efforts in providing a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The conflict file should be changed on branch `A` after the common ancestry with branch `B`. And you can double check by `git annotate` and `git log` again.

#### 1.   List the commits which modified the conflict file in branch A and branch B separately:

```
git annotate filename A
git annotate filename B
```

**Note:** the commits list in `git annotate` are ordered from old (on the top) to new (in the bottom).

Assume the output of the commands as below:

```
$ git annotate filename A
commit A1
commit A2
commit common
commit A3
commit A4

$ git annotate filename B
commit B1
commit B2
commit B3
commit common
commit B4
```

That means, after the commit ancestry `commit common`, the conflict file was changed in commit `A3` and commit `A4` in branch `A`; in branch `B`, the conflict file was changes in `commit B4` after that.

#### 2.   Show the git log as graph for the commits which changed the conflict file in all branches

And you can show the commits which changed the conflict file by graph with the command:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all -- filename
```

Then the graph will look like as below:

```
* commit A4 (branch A)
* commit A3
|   * commit B4 (branch B)
*   | commit Common
|  \
*   | commit A2
*   | commit A1
|   * commit B3
|   * commit B2
|   * commit B1
|   |
…   …
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using `--all` in `git log`. It seems this does not show merge commits and I think the problem was introduced by a merge commit that was not handled properly.

Comment: @insitu: more important, if you are using `git log ... -- filename`, note that this turns on what Git calls *History Simplification*. To eliminate the effects of simplification you can add `--full-history` to the `git log` options.  Also, `git log` often does not look very closely at merge commits; you can add `-m` to the options to make it split merge commits into multiple separate virtual commits, which can help track down mis-merges.